How to enable experimental decorators in Storybook 8 w/ NextJS/SWC
I have experimental class decorators (not the TypeScript 5 decorators) in my code and it makes the Storybook build to crash.
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@storybook/nextjs/dist/swc/next-swc-loader-patch.js):
Error:
  × Expression expected

I have read the Storybook docs about SWC and they are highly confusing. I am using Storybook 8 with the "@storybook/nextjs" framework.  When lunching storybook, in the console it says "info => Using SWC as compiler", even though Storybook doc says SWC is not enabled by default and I have not enabled SWC anywhere in the config. Why is it using SWC? Anyway.
So as per the SWC docs and the Storybook docs, I have added this to my Storybook main.ts file:
const config: StorybookConfig = {
...
swc: (config: Options, options): Options => {
        return {
            ...config,
            jsc: {
                parser: {
                    decorators: true
                }
            }
        };
    },
}

But that code here, is not even being executed. I could throw an exception there and it's not even thrown.
How I do I enable decorator support with Storybook 8 and NextJs?

Have like the same problem with entities of TypeORM. Did you solve the problem @olivierr91 ?

Unfortunately I have not solved the problem. I also use TypeORM but I have no need of the database with Storybook. The few classes that use decorators I have ended up mocking them with classes that do no use decorators. The GitHub issue is opened here: https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/discussions/26836#discussioncomment-9229427

Check out this:
// This TypeScript code attempts to configure Storybook to enable decorators using SWC with corrected type definitions.
import { StorybookConfig } from '@storybook/nextjs';
import { Options } from '@swc/core';

const config: StorybookConfig = {
  stories: [],
  addons: ['@storybook/addon-links', '@storybook/addon-essentials'],
  framework: '@storybook/nextjs',
  core: {
    builder: '@storybook/builder-webpack5'
  },
  typescript: {
    check: false,
    reactDocgen: 'react-docgen-typescript',
    reactDocgenTypescriptOptions: {
      shouldExtractLiteralValuesFromEnum: true,
      propFilter: (prop) => (prop.parent ? !/node_modules/.test(prop.parent.fileName) : true),
    },
  },
  swc: (config: Options, options: Options): Options => {
    return {
      ...config,
      jsc: {
        parser: {
          syntax: 'typescript',
          decorators: true,
          dynamicImport: true
        },
        transform: {
          legacyDecorator: true,
          decoratorMetadata: true
        }
      }
    };
  }
};

console.log('SWC Configuration for decorators:', config.swc);


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
